# Sammy.js How to disable caching template html?

Tags: javascript, caching, sammy.js

Sammy.js seems to be caching html templates used to load pages using context render

```
context.render(context.view('pages/new'), data)
```

Which is good in production setup. But during development it is pain to clear browser cache every time new.html is changed on the server.

Is there a way to disable all caching on Sammy.js ?

Answer (score 1):

You can [override the Sammy.templateCache method](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sammyjs/CNpuq12dNLA/y4wV_qZ_2osJ).

Answer (score 0):

When you load a template into the context you can provide the option `{cache: false}` as the second parameter to `load` method.

http://sammyjs.org/docs/api/0.7.0/all#Sammy.EventContext-load

Comment: how to work with context.view('pages/new') ? and also it will be good to have it as switch on/off for developer mode / production mode

Answer (score 0):

i was having an annoying trouble with mustache templates caching.
It seems this issue is not because of sammy templating system but because of chrome caching

so go to settings/general tab (you have to show developer tools and click on cogwheel in the bottom right corner) and click on disable cache.

please check this post i found for further help
http://harrywolff.com/fix-mustache-templates-from-being-cached/

hope this works for you, it helped me a lot.